# system property set in test is not visible to debugTest

Tags: gradle

When I run the following gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task debugTest(type: Test) {
    println systemProperties['PROP']
}

test {  
    systemProperties['PROP'] = 'true'   
}

$ gradle debugTest
```

I expect it to print true but it prints null.

Can someone explain why.

Comment: I suppose that `systemProperties` are defined per task instance not globally.

Answer (score 0):

you're setting the system property just for the task named `test` and not for the task named `debugTest`. You need to understand that you have 2 complete seperate tasks here, though both `test` and `debugTest` are from the same type (`Test`). One option might be apply the system properties configuration on all tasks of type Test:

```
tasks.withType(Test){
     systemProperties['PROP'] = 'true'
}
```

Another problem is, that you set the println statement in `debugTest`in the configuration block. Instead you should use a action block. Furthermore that doesn't prove at all if the property is available in the test jvm.